# Normalising KDE plots

Tags: python, pandas, plot, exponential

I wish to understand how to normalise KDE plots such that the observation count is modified by a predefined mathematical function. Take for example the tips dataset... More people have total spends averaging between $10 and $20 than people spending $30 to $40 :

```
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.kdeplot(df['total_bill'])

ax.set_title('Average Spend for a Meal\n', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Proportion of all customers', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Total Bill ($)', fontsize=14)
```

[image]

What I would like to be able to do, is 'normalise' the KDE plot such that I take into account the attractiveness of the restaurant to customers with money to spend.

There may be an exponentially decrease in the attractiveness of this restaurant as people get richer. How do I then apply an exponential function to the customer numbers in this plot, which in effect would cause the 'normalised' customer numbers of average spend around $30 to reduce, whilst also raising the normalised customer numbers who pay higher priced total bills?

Basically, turning this plot into something resembling more of a straight line!

Comment: This would be way easier by doing the whole KDE-estimation step manually instead of letting seaborn do it's magic (better access to the data; sounds you just want to do some nonlinear-scaling/multiplication). While i prefer the version in statsmodels, the sklearn-based kde-estimation is quite good to (and i'm not a big fan of scipy's).

Comment: Your answer sounds very sensible. As a noob, it didn't even occur to me to do that! The problem is, I have no idea how to implement your solution, effectively I need to apply a function to the number of observations rather than the dollar spend of each observation(which would intuitively be easier to do)?